# I want to use Firebase signInWithCredential without popup

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am running in JavaScript.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin?hl=ja#-nodejs--firebase-

When calling normally, the login window is displayed with a popup.
I want to behave the same as `signInWithRedirect`.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You should call signInWithRedirect and when it redirects back to your page, call getRedirectResult() which returns a promise with UserCredential object just same as signInWithPopup. It has more details in the link you posted. You can also take this one as a example: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/facebook-redirect.html